# Python: Turn lists into matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to python and I am wondering if I could get help with how to save vector autoregressive's results as a matrix. I have successfully gotten the VAR results following the code below.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.api import VAR
varmodel = VAR(df)
results = varmodel.fit()
print(results.coefs)
```

Then the results I got are:

```
[[[ 0.1182087  -0.1512611   0.0757709  -0.53515347]
 [ 0.35138686  0.19483162 -0.01398611 -0.13697023]
 [ 0.24409855  0.36790842  0.90589776  0.41936542]
 [ 0.18225916 -0.01139466  0.05554881  0.47024742]]]
```

The dimension of the results shown above is (row, column)= (1,4). I am wondering how I could make them a 4-by-4 matrix.

Comment: that looks a lot like a 4x4 to me

Comment: _The dimension of the results shown above is (row, column)= (1,4)._ Can you provide a [mcve]? When I create a numpy array from the output you showed, the shape is `(1, 4, 4)`.

Comment: AMC: you were correct. It's actually (1,4,4)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is 1x4x4. You can reshape it with

```
results.coefs.reshape((4, 4))
```

Comment: Thank you! I also find that results.coefs[0] would also give me a 4-by-4 matrix